# Focusing on winform if already opened?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I need to focus on form if it is already opened else i want to open new form.

I have tried this code to solve my problem but it opens new form instead of focusing already opened form.

```
foreach (var item in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            Form form1 = item as Form ;
            if (form1 != null)
            {
                form1.Activate();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                form1 = new Form ();
                form1.Show();
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: "but not working" doesn't give us any information about *how* it's not working. Also, do you really want all the forms owned by *this application*? And *any* form rather than a specific type of form? Why are you creating just a new `Form` rather than some custom form?

Comment: Above code for this problem and each time it opens new form instead to focusing on already existing form.

Comment: @MichaelS.Willy: So what debugging have you tried? Have you seen whether `Application.OpenForms` actually returns any forms? Are you interested in forms owned by this application, or all windows in the current user's session?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My *guess* is that the problem is that you're only actually looking at the first form - you've got a `break` statement in both parts of the `if` statement... and you're also just using the general `Form` type which is almost certainly inappropriate. You might want:

```
var form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<MyForm>().FirstOrDefault();
if (form != null)
{
    form.Activate();
}
else
{
    new MyForm().Show();
}
```

Comment: I want to focus any form in my app if they already opened if i am try to open new form that already opened.

Comment: @MichaelS.Willy: Well what thread is running this code? If you don't have any forms open, is the process still alive? Or are you *actually* starting a new process, and trying to find a form in another process? Because that's a very different matter.

Comment: Not for another process only for this process and not starting another process.

Comment: And now can do that. Thanks for your precious time on my problem this really helped me a lot.